# Check pending edit limit before allowing user to initiate a new edit

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, edit-limits

I've been reviewing questions in the `First Questions` review queue on Stack Overflow and frequently find it necessary to make minor edits to questions. I understand that I am limited to a specific number of pending edits, and when I reach this limit my edits will not be accepted until my pending edits are approved.

It would be helpful if this check were performed immediately upon the display of a question to review, as opposed to after carefully reviewing the question, selecting the edit option for the particular question, performing edits, and finally submitting.

Please consider performing this check as the question is initially displayed, and graying out the `Edit` option for the question if a user is not currently able to submit edits.

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, a site search of [pending edits limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Relevance&q=pending%20edits%20limit) came up with the related [Pending Edits, and Limit on Number of Edits](/q/378328).

Comment: @Rob that does appear to be a nearly identical feature-request